# How to highlight the first row in an angular mat-table?

Tags: angular, angular-material-table

I have an angular `mat-table` and a class called `table-row`. The style works and highlight the row in red if I click the row.

But what I want is to `select/highlight` the first row by default and show the red background for the raw. How can I achieve that?

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="fullName">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Name</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.fullName}}</td>
      </ng-container>
      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns; ; let i = index;" [MasterRouterLink]="['detail', row.id]" class="table-row"></tr>
    </table>
```

```
.table-row:focus {
  background: tomato;
  outline: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep `selectedRowIndex` of selected row in table. So when you select each row the `selectedRowIndex` must be updated OK? Now simply set `selectedRowIndex` to `1` in `ngOnInit` in your component.

```
<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" (click)="highlight(row)" [ngClass]="{'highlightTableColor': selectedRowIndex == row.position}">
</tr>

ngOnInit(){
    this.selectedRowIndex = 1;
  }
```

Here is working sample:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/select-mat-table-row-programatically-fwmfq2?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.ts

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by using CSS

just assign a class to the  tag like so:

```
<tr class="my-table" ...other angular stuff><td></td></tr>
```

and then use below style on the table row:

```
.my-table tr:first-child { background-color: yellow; }
```

hope it works for you

Comment: How to unselect when another row is clicked? Can it be done using CSS?

Comment: @wonderfulworld Sorry I don't know any way to do this with only CSS. you probably should use ngClass and click event for this problem

Comment: If anyone is using tailwind, maybe you'll need to define Important ("!") symbol before the clause for background color. e.g. !bg-red-500